# Joining an aggregated table with another table in Sql Server query

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables - `AfricanRatings` and `AfricanRatingsAVG`. `AfricanRatingsAVG` is the result of the query:

```
INSERT INTO AfricanRatingsAVG 
SELECT RecipeID, COUNT(*) AS Count, AVG(Rating) AS RatingAVG
FROM AfricanRatings
GROUP BY RecipeID
```

This query works fine and `AfricanRatingsAVG` is updated when a new entry is made into `AfricanRatings`.

A GridView control is used and the data from AfricanRatingsAVG displays just fine in the GridView.  My problem:  I want to also have data from a third table, AfricanRecipes also included in the same GridView.  I have tried JOIN after JOIN with no results.  The last two JOINS attempted are:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT RecipeID, COUNT(*) AS Count, AVG(Rating) AS RatingAVG
FROM AfricanRatings
GROUP BY RecipeID  ) AS AfricanRatingsAVG
JOIN (SELECT AfricanRecipes.RecipeID, AfricanRecipes.Category, AfricanRecipes.Name, AfricanRecipes.Description
FROM AfricanRecipes
GROUP BY RecipeID  ) AS AfricanRecipes ON (AfricanRatingsAVG.RecipeID = AfricanRecipes.RecipeID)"
```

AND

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT RecipeID, COUNT(*) AS Count, AVG(Rating) AS RatingAVG
FROM AfricanRatings
GROUP BY RecipeID  ) AS AfricanRatingsAVG
JOIN AfricanRecipes.RecipeID, AfricanRecipes.Category, AfricanRecipes.Name, AfricanRecipes.Description
FROM AfricanRecipes
GROUP BY RecipeID AS AfricanRecipes ON (AfricanRatingsAVG.RecipeID = AfricanRecipes.RecipeID)"
```

The first JOIN above gives the error message: Column `AfricanRecipes.Category` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause.

The second JOIN gives the error message:

> Incorrect syntax near ','

I have tried dozens of variations on the above joins with no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    AfricanRatingsAVG.*,
    AfricanRecipes.RecipeID, 
    AfricanRecipes.Category, 
    AfricanRecipes.Name, 
    AfricanRecipes.Description 
FROM (
    SELECT 
       RecipeID, 
       COUNT(*) AS RecipeCount, 
       AVG(Rating) AS RatingAVG 
    FROM AfricanRatings 
    GROUP BY RecipeID 
) AfricanRatingsAVG 
    JOIN AfricanRecipes
        ON AfricanRatingsAVG.RecipeID = AfricanRecipes.RecipeID
```

Comment: Thank you Bummi.  I tried this and get the error message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. This is what I have been running into.  You suggestion looks great to me but won't work.

Comment: @user1830924 Looks like there was just an extra `FROM` after a `JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  This works: SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT RecipeID
  ,COUNT(*) AS Count
  ,AVG(Rating) AS RatingAVG
 FROM AfricanRatings
 GROUP BY RecipeID
 ) AS AfricanRatingsAVG
JOIN (
 SELECT AfricanRecipes.RecipeID
  ,AfricanRecipes.Category
  ,AfricanRecipes.NAME
  ,AfricanRecipes.Description
 FROM AfricanRecipes
 
 ) AS AfricanRecipes ON (AfricanRatingsAVG.RecipeID = AfricanRecipes.RecipeID)